# Hibernate mapping one-to-many problem

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I am not very experienced with Hibernate and I am trying to create one-to-many mapping.

Here are relevant tables:
[image]

And here are my mapping files:

```
<hibernate-mapping package="com.xorty.mailclient.server.domain">
  <class name="Attachment" table="Attachment">
    <id name="id">
        <column name="idAttachment"></column>
    </id>
    <property name="filename">
        <column name="name"></column>
    </property>
    <property name="blob">
        <column name="file"></column>
        <type name="blob"></type>
    </property>
    <property name="mailId">
        <column name="mail_idmail"></column>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.xorty.mailclient.server.domain.Mail" table="mail">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="idmail"></id>
        <property name="content">
            <column name="body"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="ownerAddress">
            <column name="account_address"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="title">
            <column name="head"></column>
        </property>
        <set name="receivers" table="mail_has_contact" cascade="all">
            <key column="mail_idmail"></key>
            <many-to-many column="contact_address" class="com.xorty.mailclient.client.domain.Contact"></many-to-many>
        </set>
        <bag name="attachments" cascade="save-update, delete" inverse="true">
        <key column="mail_idmail" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.xorty.mailclient.server.domain.Attachment"/>
    </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In plain english, one mail has more attachments. 
When I try to do CRUD on mail *without* attachments, everyting works just fine. When I add some attachment to mail, I cannot perform any CRUD operation.

I end up with following trace:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at domain.DatabaseTest.testPersistMailWithAttachment(DatabaseTest.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`maildb`.`attachment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Attachment_mail1` FOREIGN KEY (`mail_idmail`) REFERENCES `mail` (`idmail`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 27 more
```

Thank you

**EDIT:** On hvgotcodes proposal:

```
package com.xorty.mailclient.server.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import com.xorty.mailclient.client.domain.Account;
import com.xorty.mailclient.client.domain.AttachmentDTO;
import com.xorty.mailclient.client.domain.Contact;
import com.xorty.mailclient.client.domain.MailDTO;

/**
 * Heavy weight Hibernate Mail
 * @author MisoV
 * @version 0.1
 */
public class Mail implements Serializable {

    private List<Attachment> attachments = new ArrayList<Attachment>();

    private String content;
    private int id;
    private boolean isNew;
    private Account owner;
    private String ownerAddress;
    private Set<Contact> receivers = new HashSet<Contact>();
    private String sender;
    private String title;
    /**
     * Hibernate purposes
     */
    public Mail() { // $codepro.audit.disable
    }
    /**
     * Unwraps light DTO object to heavy Hibernate object.
     * @param dto Corresponding DTO class.
     */
    public Mail(final MailDTO dto) {
        for (final AttachmentDTO attachmentDTO : dto.getAttachments()) {
            attachments.add(new Attachment(attachmentDTO));
        }
        content = dto.getContent();
        id = dto.getId();
        isNew = dto.isNew();
        owner = dto.getOwner();
        ownerAddress = dto.getOwnerAddress();
        receivers = dto.getReceivers();
        sender = dto.getSender();
        title = dto.getTitle();
    }

    /**
     * Inserts new attachment
     * @param attachment
     */
    public void addAttachment(final Attachment attachment) {
        attachments.add(attachment);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Mail)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Mail other = (Mail) obj;
        if (attachments == null) {
            if (other.attachments != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!attachments.equals(other.attachments)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (content == null) {
            if (other.content != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!content.equals(other.content)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isNew != other.isNew) {
            return false;
        }
        if (owner == null) {
            if (other.owner != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!owner.equals(other.owner)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (ownerAddress == null) {
            if (other.ownerAddress != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!ownerAddress.equals(other.ownerAddress)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (receivers == null) {
            if (other.receivers != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!receivers.equals(other.receivers)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (sender == null) {
            if (other.sender != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!sender.equals(other.sender)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (title == null) {
            if (other.title != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!title.equals(other.title)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return the attachments
     */
    public List<Attachment> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }
    /**
     * @return the content
     */
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the owner
     */
    public Account getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    /**
     * @return the ownerAddress
     */
    public String getOwnerAddress() {
        return ownerAddress;
    }
    /**
     * @return the receivers
     */
    public Set<Contact> getReceivers() {
        return receivers;
    }
    /**
     * @return the sender
     */
    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }
    /**
     * @return the title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((attachments == null) ? 0 : attachments.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((content == null) ? 0 : content.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + (isNew ? 1231 : 1237);
        result = prime * result + ((owner == null) ? 0 : owner.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((ownerAddress == null) ? 0 : ownerAddress.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((receivers == null) ? 0 : receivers.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((sender == null) ? 0 : sender.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * @return the isNew
     */
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }
    /**
     * @param attachments the attachments to set
     */
    public void setAttachments(final List<Attachment> attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }
    /**
     * @param content the content to set
     */
    public void setContent(final String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @param isNew the isNew to set
     */
    public void setNew(final boolean isNew) {
        this.isNew = isNew;
    }
    /**
     * @param owner the owner to set
     */
    public void setOwner(final Account owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    /**
     * @param ownerAddress the ownerAddress to set
     */
    public void setOwnerAddress(final String ownerAddress) {
        this.ownerAddress = ownerAddress;
    }
    /**
     * @param receivers the receivers to set
     */
    public void setReceivers(final Set<Contact> receivers) {
        this.receivers = receivers;
    }
    /**
     * @param sender the sender to set
     */
    public void setSender(final String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    /**
     * @param title the title to set
     */
    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Attachment:

```
// $codepro.audit.disable com.instantiations.assist.eclipse.analysis.audit.rule.effectivejava.alwaysOverridetoString.alwaysOverrideToString
/**
 * 
 */
package com.xorty.mailclient.server.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialException;

import com.xorty.mailclient.client.domain.AttachmentDTO;

/**
 * Heavy weight Hibernate Attachment
 * @author MisoV
 * @version 0.1
 */
public class Attachment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2047475939737947104L;
    private SerialBlob blob;
    private byte[] content;
    private String contentid;
    private String contenttype;
    private String filename;
    private int id;
    private int mailId;


    /**
     *  Hibernate purposes
     */
    public Attachment() { // $codepro.audit.disable emptyMethod
    }

    /**
     * Unwraps DTO to heavy weight hibernate object.
     * @param dto
     */
    public Attachment(final AttachmentDTO dto) {
        content = dto.getContent();
        contentid = dto.getContentid();
        contenttype = dto.getContenttype();
        filename = dto.getFilename();
        id = dto.getId();
        mailId = dto.getMailId();
        try {
            blob = new SerialBlob(content);
        } catch (final SerialException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the blob
     */
    public SerialBlob getBlob() {
        return blob;
    }

    /**
     * @return the content
     */
    public byte[] getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contentid
     */
    public String getContentid() {
        return contentid;
    }
    /**
     * @return the contenttype
     */
    public String getContenttype() {
        return contenttype;
    }
    /**
     * @return the filename
     */
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }
    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the mailId
     */
    public int getMailId() {
        return mailId;
    }
    /**
     * @param blob the blob to set
     */
    public void setBlob(final SerialBlob blob) {
        this.blob = blob;
    }
    /**
     * @param content the content to set
     */
    public void setContent(final byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    /**
     * @param contentid the contentid to set
     */
    public void setContentid(final String contentid) {
        this.contentid = contentid;
    }
    /**
     * @param contenttype the contenttype to set
     */
    public void setContenttype(final String contenttype) {
        this.contenttype = contenttype;
    }
    /**
     * @param filename the filename to set
     */
    public void setFilename(final String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(final int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mailId the mailId to set
     */
    public void setMailId(final int mailId) {
        this.mailId = mailId;
    }


}
```

**EDIT2:**

Hibernate actually performs insert:

```
insert into Attachment (name, file, mail_idmail, idAttachment) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

And values are correctly set. It doesn't fail on session.save nor on session.get (it even gets correct copy). It fails on committing transaction.

Only thing I can get of it is: `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`maildb`.`attachment`, CONSTRAINT`fk_Attachment_mail1`FOREIGN KEY (`mail_idmail`) REFERENCES`mail`(`idmail`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

Comment: Although this doesn't relate directly to your question, do you really want to use a `List` to map this relationship as opposed to a `Bag`?  Seems like the order of attachments on a message probably wouldn't matter as long as they are all there.

Comment: And I did change it to Bag, with no result though (exact same error as with list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting a constraint violation exception.  I think it is on the foreign key from attachment to mail, as evidenced by

```
foreign key constraint fails (`maildb`.`attachment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Attachment_mail1` FOREIGN KEY (`mail_idmail`)
```

I noticed you are not specifying a generator for your id.  See this documentation

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

since you did not specify the generator, the default is 'assigned' which means you have to programmatically assign the ids to the objects *before* you save them, which might or might not be what you want.

You didn't show us the code for how your Mail entity relates to the Attachment entity, or how you create your entities, which would all me to help more...depending on how you do it, hibernate might or might not be able to assign the foreign key in the attachment class.

EDIT --  from your comments, you are missing a few things.  Try assigning the id of the mail entity to the attachment in your addAttachment method on mail.  If you want the db to assign the id, you need to look up how to have the id column of the tables auto-increment for whatever RDBMS system you are using, and then you change add a generator to the id mappings of the entities.  The generator will probably be 'identity' or 'increment' depending on the RDBMS.

Comment: @xorty, and your Attachment class?

Comment: @xorty, do you want your db to assign the values for id or do you want to do it yourself?

Comment: @hvgotcodes Now I pasted full implementation. I use hashCode as ID right now, though I don't know if it's good idea. Actually I wouldn't mind if it was handled by DB.

Comment: fyi - DTO mail and attachment are same, except that Attachment uses java.sql package which couldn't be used at client side, so it needs to be this way

Comment: @hvgtcodes - to your edit, if you looks at Attachment's constructor it actually has assigned mail id: mailId = dto.getMailId(); So addAttachment method already works with correct ID

Comment: @xorty, yes i just noticed that.  hmmm. Im not sure -- the error from the db definitely indicates that when the save actually happens, the foreign key is not getting set.  Try looking at the values on the entities in the debugger right before they are getting saved.  also, configure hibernate to log the sql and make sure it is correct.

Comment: @hvgtcodes see edit 2 ... I believe it's something with mapping, that's the area where I lack knowledge ... Or maybe something with mapping SerialBlob to MySQL blob?

Comment: @xorty, that error, on the foreign key constraint, means that the FK from attachment to mail is incorrect.  Do you have a unit test for this?  If so, try manually setting the ids.  If you don't have a unit test, write one ;)  It might be that your hashcodes are being generated incorrectly

Comment: Yes I am actually writing unit tests, and seting all manually :( Hash codes were different, so I modified hashCode methods. Now they're same but it didn't help though.

Comment: @xorty, are you sure the exception is the same, after you modified hashcode?

Comment: Thank you anyway, maybe it's just cursed ;D

Comment: i think its something relatively simple, but without being able to access and play with the code I can't know.  You might want to step away for a while and come back later -- sometimes that helps

Comment: Yeah its 04:15 AM here ... so I'll go sleep and see tommorrow :/

Comment: @xorty i had some more ideas: 1) try saving the mail first, then saving the attachments.  2) try not saving the blob, if you can.  Just save the mail and the attachment metadata.

Comment: @hvgotcodes thanx for fresh ideas. So - 1) works, 2) not possible ... So I can save mail then loop thru it's attachments and persist them. But I am afriad this is why they invented mapping so I don't have to do it like this :D

Comment: @xorty, yes i agree completely.  But at least you have a fallback so you can move on, then later you can come back and fix this.  Now try this.  Save the mail without the attachements, then add the attachments, then update the mail.

Comment: @hvgtcodes - it works that way ... but I made update as joel proposed - I am using now full Mail instance not only it's ID in Attachment class. Still no luck with mapping though.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to make a bi-directionnal relation, you should indicate to your Attachment the Mail object and not only the Id :

In the Attcahment class, remove

> private int mailId;
>   and replace it by 
>   private Mail mail;

with the correct setter and getter.

In the Xml mapping file:

> ```
> <property name="mailId">
>     <column name="mail_idmail"></column>
> </property>
> ```

should be replaced by :

> ```
> <many-to-one name="mail"
>              column="mail_idmail" not-null="true"/>
> ```

By the way, your hashCode/equals methods are crap.
You should read this : http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode
Anyway, it's better to not override them than have them wrong.

Comment: Every attachment should have mail property which already has List of attachments ??